# what is the difference between unsqueez_ in pytorch and epxand_dim in keras and what will be the shape of output after using it?

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I am a beginner in keras and I have a pytorch code that I need to change it to keras, but I could not understand some part of it. specially I have problems in the size of the output shape.  the shape of `image` is (:, 3,32,32) and the first dimension of `image` is the size of the batch. now, my question is: what this line do and what is the output shape:

```
    image_yuv_ch = image[:, channel, :, :].unsqueeze_(1)
```

it adds a dimension in position 1? what is the output shape?:(
the size of filters was (64,8,8) and then we have `filters.unsqueez_(1)`, is this means the new shape of `filters` is `(64,1,8,8)`?
what does this line do?  `image_conv = F.conv2d(image_yuv_ch, filters, stride=8)` is it the same as conv2d in keras what is the shape of output tensor from it? I also could not understand what view do? I know it tries to show tensor in new shape but in the below code I could not understand the output shape after each `unsqueez_`, `permute` or `view`. could you please tell me what is the output shape of each line? Thank you in advance.

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
def apply_conv(self, image, filter_type: str):



        if filter_type == 'dct':
            filters = self.dct_conv_weights
        elif filter_type == 'idct':
            filters = self.idct_conv_weights
        else:
            raise('Unknown filter_type value.')

        image_conv_channels = []
        for channel in range(image.shape[1]):
            image_yuv_ch = image[:, channel, :, :].unsqueeze_(1)
            image_conv = F.conv2d(image_yuv_ch, filters, stride=8)
            image_conv = image_conv.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
            image_conv = image_conv.view(image_conv.shape[0], image_conv.shape[1], image_conv.shape[2], 8, 8)
            image_conv = image_conv.permute(0, 1, 3, 2, 4)
            image_conv = image_conv.contiguous().view(image_conv.shape[0],
                                                  image_conv.shape[1]*image_conv.shape[2],
                                                  image_conv.shape[3]*image_conv.shape[4])

            image_conv.unsqueeze_(1)

            # image_conv = F.conv2d()
            image_conv_channels.append(image_conv)

        image_conv_stacked = torch.cat(image_conv_channels, dim=1)

        return image_conv_stacked
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are Keras-user or Tensorflow-user and trying to learn Pytorch. 
You should go to the [website](https://pytorch.org/docs/) of Pytorch document to understand more about each operation.

- `unsqueeze` is to expand the dim by 1 of the tensor. The underscore in `unsqueeze_()` means this is `in-place` function.
- `view()` can be understood as `.reshape()` in keras.
- `permute()` is to switch multiple dimensions of tensor. For example:

```py
x = torch.randn(1,2,3) # shape [1,2,3]
x = torch.permute(2,0,1) # shape [3,1,2]
```

In order to know the shape of the tensor after each operation, just simply add `print(x.size())`. For example:

```
image_conv = image_conv.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
print(image_conv.size())

image_conv = image_conv.view(image_conv.shape[0], image_conv.shape[1], 
print(image_conv.size())

image_conv.shape[2], 8, 8)
print(image_conv.size())

image_conv = image_conv.permute(0, 1, 3, 2, 4)
print(image_conv.size())
```

The big difference between Pytorch and Tensorflow (back-end of Keras) is that Pytorch will generate a dynamic graph, rather than a static graph as Tensorflow. Your way of defining a model would not work properly in Pytorch since the weights of `conv` will not be save in `model.parameters()` which can't be optimized during the backpropagation.

One more comment, please check this [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module) to learn how to define a proper model using Pytorch:

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
       x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
       return F.relu(self.conv2(x))
```

#### The code for the comment:

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn(8, 3, 32, 32)
print(x.shape)
torch.Size([8, 3, 32, 32])
channel = 1
y = x[:, channel, :, :]
print(y.shape)
torch.Size([8, 32, 32])

y = y.unsqueeze_(1)
print(y.shape)
torch.Size([8, 1, 32, 32])
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your learning!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have to change this pytorch code to Keras because I want to use it in Keras. because I do not have pytorch on my system, I cannot implement it to see the output shape:( if my input image has the shape of (:,3,32,32) and the first and second elements are batch size and the number of channels, what will be the output of unsqueez_(1)?

Comment: another question is for conv2d. in Keras, in Conv2D we specify the number of filters, the size of filters and stride separately. here we send filters to conv2d with shape 64x8x8. now, does pytorch consider 64 as the number of filters and 8x8 as the size of filters?

Comment: `(:, 3, 32, 32) -> unsqueeze_(1)` you will get `(:, 1, 3, 32, 32)`. But in your code in the question:  `image[:, channel, :, :].unsqueeze_(1)`, we have `image[:, channel, :, :] -> (:, 32, 32)` and then `unsqueeze_(1)`  to get `(:, 1, 32, 32)`.

Comment: sorry, this means, it is not important what is the value of the channel, right? when I use image[:,channel,:,:].unsqueeze_(1) the output shape for all values in the channel will be (:,1,32,32)? Does this mean unsqueeze_ do noting here? maybe my question is simple but I am really confused with these shape changes in the above code:(

Comment: also, the shape of filters was (64,8,8) then after unsqueezing_1(1) it will become (64,1,8,8), right?

Comment: now based on your explanation is it possible to convolve image[:,1,32,32] with filters[64,1,8,8]? because in keras it produces error:( what is the difference between nn.Conv2d and F.conv2d? because in the above code, F.conv2d is used?!

Comment: maybe you should start learning how to build a model in Pytorch. F.conv2d is a method to perform convolution of a tensor with filters while `nn.Conv2d` is a module which provide convolution operation as well as encapsulating the parameters of conv to learn in the later.

Comment: sure, I still need your help:( I want to be sure. image[:, channel, :, :].unsqueeze_(1) for different value of channel will be (:,1,32,32), right?

Comment: in the above code, we had F.conv2d so I want to know is it consider (64,1,8,8) as 64 filters with size 8x8? this network tries to do some changes on the output of one layer via the above function and (64,1,8,8) will not be used in training. it is used to change the image.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the code for in the updated answer. You can take a look and try it yourself. Enjoy!

Comment: to the last question, yes. please read the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) to know more. `F.conv2d` only use for what behind the `nn.Conv2d` works, not a component for building and training a model  :)

Comment: don't be so conservative from what you learned in keras/tensorflow to Pytorch. Once you understand, it's gonna be so much easy :)

Comment: Thank you. is it possible to install pytorch and keras in the same computer? do you know any links I can implement pytorch code online without needing to install in my computer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192649/discussion-between-nadia-and-david-ng).

Comment: I read this doc but for example, in some cases like unsqueez_1 it did not say if I use sth like my code, it will not produce a new dimension:(